# Should Comments indicating possible duplication be flagged when incorrect?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, comments

Does it help the community to flag comments that say "duplicate of question X" when it isn't an actual duplicate though the person who commented thought it was?

Should this be flagged or deleted or not?

Answer (score 2):

You should not flag any comment unless it belongs to any of the followings:

[image]

If you don't agree with the comment with a duplicate link, you can make a comment using @ + commenter's user name or edit your question explaining why your question is not a duplicate. Other users with more than 3K reputation will judge based on your comment or edit.

As @pnuts explained in the comments, the *possible duplicate* comment is auto-generated and it doesn't necessarily mean your question is a duplicate. It will be judged by the community vote.

If you really object to it, it is not actually discouraged to flag the comment and a moderator could delete the comment if (s)he agrees with your flag. However, the link will still remain in the close-vote review queue and it will be reviewed by users. You can argue why it isn't a dupe in your comment or edit so that the flagger or close-voter may retract his/her flag or close-vote.

Comment: Saying that it is a duplicate when obviously it is not, is not constructive in my opinion. Maybe we could be more strict about things like that. It comes up very often and people need to argue why it is or isn't a dupe.
But your answer is a good answer i'm not disagreeing with you. you have very good points!

Comment: @AustinW. If you really object to it, it is not actually discouraged to flag the comment and a moderator could delete the comment. However, the link will remain in the close-vote review queue and it will still be reviewed by users. You can argue why it isn't a dupe in your comment or edit so that the flagger or close-voter may retract his/her flag or close-vote.

Comment: I appreciate a comment saying "this is not a duplicate because X." If I see that in review, I'll always give it extra consideration.

Comment: The last item in the list is “other…” so it's explicitly not meant to be exhaustive and invoking it is not very helpful.